# Pandas Get Max values within each group, by group sum

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(
    { 
        'Date' : np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime(2020,1,1),periods=5),20),
        'Product' : np.random.choice(['Milk','Brandy','Beer'],20)   ,    
     'Quantity' : np.random.randint(10,99,20)
        
    }  
)
df.groupby(['Date','Product']).sum()
```

This will give,

[image]

I would like to get the max values of the sum within the group what is the best way to do it?

Expected result for my random sample value would be.

[image]

How can I achieve this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain with another groupby, this time on your first level of your index (product) and get the max:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Product']).sum().groupby(level=1).max()
```

```
         Quantity
Product          
Beer          160
Brandy         97
Milk          245
```

---

To get the date as well, use `sort_values` with `tail`:

```
(
    df.groupby(['Date','Product']).sum()
    .sort_values('Quantity')
    .groupby(level=1)
    .tail(1)
)
```

```
        Date Product  Quantity
0 2020-01-04    Beer        81
1 2020-01-03    Milk       186
2 2020-01-03  Brandy       212
```

Comment: Can I also get the corresponding Date as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
df.groupby(['Date','Product']).sum().reset_index().groupby(
    ['Product']).max().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Product Date        Quantity
0   Beer    2020-01-04  151
1   Brandy  2020-01-05  72
2   Milk    2020-01-05  188
```

Comment: Are you sure the corresponding Date value is correct?

Comment: You `max` is taken over the whole dataframe, thus `Date` and `Quantity`. That is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Check with `drop_duplicates`

```
df.groupby(['Date','Product'],as_index=False).sum().sort_values('Quantity').drop_duplicates('Product',keep='last')
         Date Product  Quantity
11 2020-01-05    Milk       119
10 2020-01-05  Brandy       165
5  2020-01-03    Beer       302
```